# gradle generated startScript for windows produces "input line is too long"

Tags: windows, command-line, gradle, spring-boot

using versions:

```
springBoot = 1.2.3.RELEASE
gradle = 2.3
```

When building a self executing springBoot distribution (gradle task bootRepackage) the gradle generated classpath in the windows start batch is very huge which leads windows to abort the start script with error "input line is too long".

How to workaround this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

I found following solution by manipulating the generated start-batch for windows by shortening the huge classpath to a simple

```
    %APP_HOME%\lib\*
```

which is allowed since java6.

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        def winScriptFile  = file getWindowsScript()
        def winFileText = winScriptFile.text
        winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll('set CLASSPATH=.*', 'rem original CLASSPATH declaration replaced by:\nset CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\\\*')
        winScriptFile.text = winFileText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `classpath = files('lib/*')` to your startScripts block for the same result, e.g.:

```
application {
    ...
    startScripts {
        ...
        classpath = files('lib/*')
    }
}
```